# nodeclipse: command not found on Linux after install it

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, nodeclipse

I have nodejs and npm installed.
I tested `npm -v` and `nodejs -v` it worked, showed the current version.

I used the `nodeclipse -p` command line in my empty folder to create the project structure, but I received the error: **command not found**

I uninstalled the nodeclipse with npm uninstall and installed again with sudo npm install and did not work.

I used the root account and run the npm install also did not work.

I don´t found the npm or nodejs references to set the environment variable to set the nodeclipse or config it.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Did you install nodeclipse as global module with the -g argument?

Comment: I do not remember. I will do it now.

Comment: `npm install -g nodeclipse` did you try this? You have to use sudo on Linux or administrator account on windows

Comment: I Did execution with `-g` but not yet succeeded.  
The error occurs:  
`paranhos@pc-principal:~/workspace-javascript/react-sample$ nodeclipse -h`  
`/usr/bin/env: “node”: File or directory not found`

Comment: exactly this command `sudo npm install -g nodeclipse`

Comment: after this command, I tryed with `nodeclipse -h`

Comment: but not yet succeeded. The error occurs:  
`/usr/bin/env: “node”: File or directory not found`

Comment: I uninstalled and installed with the root user, but it is the same error.

Comment: @FernandoZamperin 
I solved the problem.
I analyzed the bashrc and etc/profile on Linux.
then analyzed the usr/bin folder of the executables.
Then I created a symbolic link to the nodejs command.

You can accept my answer to increase my reputation, please?

Comment: also in https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/214

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**
There is a bug in nodeclipse plugin that recognizes Node.js as `node` command the Windows installation.
In **Linux** the nodeclipse plugin tries to find the command `node` and can not find. Why on Linux, the `nodejs` command is utilized for the Node.js installed.
**printing error in the terminal**

```
paranhos@pc-principal:~/workspace-javascript/react-sample$ nodeclipse -p
/usr/bin/env: "node": File or directory not found
```

> **Solution:** Create a Symbolic Link

```
sudo ln -s "$ (which nodejs)" /usr/bin/node
```

or

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

**Successful result**

```
paranhos @ pc-main: ~ $ node -v 
v4.4.2 
paranhos @ pc-main: ~ $ nodejs -v 
v4.4.2 
paranhos @ pc-main: ~ $ nodeclipse -h    
Usage: nodeclipse [arguments]    
--help Nodeclipse install > is Nodeclipse CLI Installer Help
```

Answer (score 0):

I also can solve this question, installing the new nodejs version for my linux distro.
Getting ".deb" package directly and following the instructions in the url´s:

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

In the version 4.4.7 or latest was Included `node` and `nodejs` as command.

Answer (score 0):

**Install** with npm install -g nodeclipse

then work **nodeclipse** command

Hope work fine